# Time series document with mongoose node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this below.

```
const activePowerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nr: {
type: String,
required: true,
minlength: 2,
maxlength: 50
},

 value: { 
type: [Number],
required: true,
minlength: 0
},

 epoch_timestamp: {
type: Number,
required: true,
minlength: 0
}
});
```

now the data should be pushed into "value" for 5 mins in a document and after 5 mins instead of pushing into "value" it creates  another document and push the data into "value" for next 5 mins and so on e.g.

```
{"nr": "test_nr", "epoch_timestamp":"1556114198", "value":[200,300,500,200]}
```

and after 5 mins a new document like..

```
{"nr": "test_nr", "epoch_timestamp":"1557114198", "value":[1200,2300,5400,1200]} and so on..
```

is there any thing present within mongoose or do i have to make a logic to check the time if its less then 5 min then push into array and after every 5 mins a new document?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that comes to my mind is creating a new collection which will have only 1 document:

```
const lastEpochSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    timestamp: { type: Date },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('LastEpoch', lastEpochSchema);
```

And then every time you want to insert a new `value` into `activePower` you simply query for:

```
const lastEpoch = await LastEpoch.findOne();
```

Then compare it with current `Date.now()` and if the difference is more than 5*1000 (5 secs) then update `LastEpoch` and insert a new document into `activePower`. If less than 5 secs - push values to the current `activePower` where `activePower.epoch_timestamp` will be equal to `LastEpoch`.